# usability playing diablo II and starcraft 2 on a mac with magic mouse

Tags: starcraft-2, macos, diablo-ii

I'm currently playing through Mass Effect 2 on the Xbox 360 and it is probably the best gaming experience I've ever had. Now that it's coming to an end and I get to eagerly anticipate ME3 with other fans, it was highly recommended that I check out Diablo II and Starcraft 2.

Since those titles are not available on the Xbox 360, I was curious what caveats would one have playing them on a Mac using a mouse with one button (the magic mouse)? Is it do able? Is there another peripheral/mouse I can purchase to make the game play more enjoyable? I got a brand new core i7 iMac with a 2GB graphics card and 16GB of ram, so I'm not worried about sheer performance. I'm more or less worried about the usability of the game when playing with a one button mouse and what I can do to resolve any inconveniences that might come with it.

Comment: The magic mouse isn't a one button mouse "Magic Mouse functions as a two-button mouse when you enable Secondary Click in System Preferences".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Two-button click
>
> Magic Mouse functions as a two-button mouse when you enable Secondary Click in System Preferences. Left-handed users can reassign left and right click, as well.

http://www.apple.com/magicmouse/

Most games will allow you to configure the controls anyways, so there shouldn't be a *dire* need for a right mouse button. And of course, you can absolutely buy another mouse or other peripherals.